# Best way to store user data while integrating google login

Tags: python, reactjs, google-signin

I am integrating google login into an app I am creating with react and want to store user data in the database. I want to store the least amount of data and my original plan was to just store the token, then compare the token when the user signs to see if they are registered, and then populate the front end with their data using JWTdecode. I realized after that the token seems to change every time and there is not a set token. I wanted to ask the public from their experience what the best way of integrating google login is that stores the least amount of user data in the backend databases. Please note, I am aware the database info is hardcoded right now and that is not best practice, that will change I just started working on this and that is why it is.

```
// File: App.js
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { jwtDecode } from 'jwt-decode';


function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLoginSuccess = (credentialResponse) => {
    const token = credentialResponse.credential;
    const decoded = jwtDecode(token);


    console.log('Decoded JWT:', decoded);
  
    // Use decoded data
    const userInfo = {
      name: decoded.name,
      email: decoded.email,
     // given_name: decoded.given_name,
      //given_name: decoded.given_name,
      // Add other fields as necessary
    };

    //send User info to server (Python flask will run on localhost port 5000)
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(token),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Handle response data
      console.log(data);
      navigate('/welcome', { state: { user: userInfo } });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  };
  
    


  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleLogin
        onSuccess={handleLoginSuccess}
        onError={() => {
          console.log('Login Failed');
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)



@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register_user():
    token = request.json
    print(token)

    # Connect to database
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1', database='unigpt')
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        # Check if user already exists
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE token = %s", (token,))
        if cursor.fetchone():
            return jsonify({'message': 'User already exists'}), 409

        # Insert new user
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (token) VALUES (%s)", (token,))
        conn.commit()
        return jsonify({'message': 'User registered successfully'}), 201

    except Error as e:
        print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
        return jsonify({'message': 'Error while registering user'}), 500

    finally:
        if conn.is_connected():
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```